# How to get actual project output using microsoft.build.evaluation.project in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, project, csproj, vcxproj

I need to know the actual output file name full path in a project.
I use microsoft.build.evaluation.project to open a project with the correct properties, and i tried using the properties TargetPath, TargetDir, TargetFileName, but i can't find a consistent property to give me the output file name with the path.
In some projects it works, and in some it doesn't. I work both on csproj files and vcxproj files.

Answer (score 2):

Output path is related to project folder. You can get its value from project file via property `OutputPath` (suppose `project` is an instance of `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project`)

```
var outputPath = project.GetPropertyValue("OutputPath")
```

Then you can use Path.Combine to concatenate your output path and project folder

```
var fullpath =  Path.Combine(projectDirectory, outputPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ask's answer:

If you need to get an OutputPath for some other configuration than the current one (Release for example), you should do next:

```
project.SetProperty("Configuration", "Release");
project.ReevaluateIfNecessary();
var outputPath = project.GetPropertyValue("OutputPath");
```

or

```
ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.SetGlobalProperty("Configuration", "Release");
load project
var outputPath = project.GetPropertyValue("OutputPath");
```