# How to capture output of msbuild in a variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to get the output of the below into a variable, how can I do it?

```
var proj = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(args[1]);
var msbuild = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(proj);
msbuild.Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `public bool Build (Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger logger);` to build with a logger and get the ouput from this.
Check this for how to use a logger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger?view=netframework-4.7.2

Edit: Add sample code

Create a custom logger:

```
public class ExtendLogger : Microsoft.Build.Logging.ConsoleLogger
{
    private string savedLog;

    public ExtendLogger(): base()
    {
        base.WriteHandler = this.SaveLog;
    }

    void SaveLog(string message)
    {
        savedLog += message;
    }

    public string GetLog()
    {
        return savedLog;
    }
}
```

And use this with your code:

```
var proj = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(args[1]);
var msbuild = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(proj);
var logger = new ExtendLogger();
bool result = msbuild.Build(logger);
string logString = logger.GetLog();
Console.WriteLine("Build success?: " + result.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(logString );
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you use `Microsoft.Build.Logging.ConsoleLogger`, the logs will be printed directly to the console.

Comment: Thanks, I don't really understand how to use ILogger to come with result, could you please come up with a sample code snippet

Comment: @EmilyWong
Sorry, it seems I misunderstood your question. If you want to get the output path, please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139757/how-to-get-actual-project-output-using-microsoft-build-evaluation-project-in-c-s

Comment: no i dont want output path, i want the console standard output.

Comment: @EmilyWong Please check my sample code and see if it works.